# How to add a Return before a specific word (and also move subsequent text to the next line)

Tags: notepad++

I have the phrase 'Film:' towards the end of some of the lines in a notepad++ file with over 37900 lines of data. How can I find this phrase (and the text following it), to the next line? Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Have been doing this manually so far. It's a pain,. and have just reached 1000 lines after spending a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Search and replace: Find what: _Film:(.*)$_, Replace with: _\nFilm:\1_. And check the _Regular Expression_ Search Mode.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?=\bFilm:)`
- Replace with: `\n`        # you can use `\r\n` depending on your platform
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?=             # begin positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \b          # word boundary
    Film:       # literally
)               # end lookahead
```